# In the Rails database should Strings be stored downcased or left as is?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am storing street addresses and restaurant names in my database under. Whenever I return the name or address I want the original case to be untouched.
However in the future I plan to implement searching over the name and street address field, and I don't want the searching to be case sensitive.

How should I best store these fields?

Comment: ... If you want to maintain the original capitalization then the answer seems obvious.

Answer (score 2):

There is no term like `Rails database`
The desired effect can be easily achieved for example in MySQL by using a *case insensitive* collation for your address table / column. For example `utf8_general_ci` is such collation - in fact all that end with `ci` are *case insensitive*

Having such collation of storing data will give you the ability to easily search the database without to worry about letter cases and preserve the original format.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to decide if data case sensitive from user perspective. If you absolutely sure that data you going to store insensitive possibly you still don't need to store it down case, because insensitive search still available for you even if data stored in database in mixed case.

Also if you using postgresql and need insensitive search, you may create [functional index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/indexes-expressional.html) like this:

```
CREATE INDEX test1_lower_col1_idx ON test1 (lower(col1));
```

and after that you can search using where lower(col1) without postgresql recalculate lower for every col1.